# API that provide today weather and next 5 day weather forcast

Tags: php, html, weather

Attempted using the Yahoo Weather

like this:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location=%22LEXX0003%22&format=json&u=c
```

However, the weather is next 4 days only. are there any other free weather API recommend? I am not heavy user so it seems the charged plan is not required.

Comment: This has 5 day and 16 day . http://openweathermap.org/api This is also another good alternative http://forecast.io/. I used that for a weather app I tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OpenWeatherMap API. It goes up to five days in advance. :)
http://openweathermap.org/forecast5